# Why can't dunder/magic methods be set in unittest.mock.Mock.configure_mock?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

I was writing some unit test in python and needed to mock a very general [collections.abc.Sized](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sized), so I set off creating a Mock with a `__len__` method whose return value is any int I want.

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock

sized = Mock(**{"__len__.return_value": 8})
```

Which failed with `AttributeErrorgave: __len__` and produced the traceback at the end of the post, while the following works:

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock

sized = Mock()
sized.__len__.return_value = 8

# or
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

sized = MagicMock(**{"__len__.return_value": 8})
```

Reading down the traceback we see that:

1. CallableMixin's `__init__` is called.
2. kwargs passed to Mock's `__init__` method get passed to [`Mock.configure_mock()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.configure_mock)
3. the kwargs name is `getattr()`ed on the Mock itself
4. Mock `__getattr__` method raises an AttributeError if attribute name is magic, that is if `'__%s__' % name[2:-2] == name`.

This seems like a very arbitrary limitation and I wonder if there is a reason for Mock not to accept magic methods in [`Mock.configure_mock()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.configure_mock).

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 Mock(**{"__len__.return_value": 0})

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.3/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py:1086, in CallableMixin.__init__(self, spec, side_effect, return_value, wraps, name, spec_set, parent, _spec_state, _new_name, _new_parent, **kwargs)
   1082 def __init__(self, spec=None, side_effect=None, return_value=DEFAULT,
   1083              wraps=None, name=None, spec_set=None, parent=None,
   1084              _spec_state=None, _new_name='', _new_parent=None, **kwargs):
   1085     self.__dict__['_mock_return_value'] = return_value
-> 1086     _safe_super(CallableMixin, self).__init__(
   1087         spec, wraps, name, spec_set, parent,
   1088         _spec_state, _new_name, _new_parent, **kwargs
   1089     )
   1091     self.side_effect = side_effect

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.3/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py:457, in NonCallableMock.__init__(self, spec, wraps, name, spec_set, parent, _spec_state, _new_name, _new_parent, _spec_as_instance, _eat_self, unsafe, **kwargs)
    454 __dict__['_mock_unsafe'] = unsafe
    456 if kwargs:
--> 457     self.configure_mock(**kwargs)
    459 _safe_super(NonCallableMock, self).__init__(
    460     spec, wraps, name, spec_set, parent,
    461     _spec_state
    462 )

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.3/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py:625, in NonCallableMock.configure_mock(self, **kwargs)
    623 obj = self
    624 for entry in args:
--> 625     obj = getattr(obj, entry)
    626 setattr(obj, final, val)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.3/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py:636, in NonCallableMock.__getattr__(self, name)
    634         raise AttributeError("Mock object has no attribute %r" % name)
    635 elif _is_magic(name):
--> 636     raise AttributeError(name)
    637 if not self._mock_unsafe:
    638     if name.startswith(('assert', 'assret', 'asert', 'aseert', 'assrt')):

AttributeError: __len__
```

Comment: Have a look at [MagicMock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?highlight=asyncmock#unittest.mock.MagicMock) - it creates most magic methods automatically.

Comment: I know of MagicMock, but I just needed `__len__` set to my choice of int, and I wonder why a two step process is needed.

Comment: It is not needed if you use `MagicMock` instead of `Mock` is what I meant - but looks like I didn't understand your  question.